# HTTP GET request using C++ WinSock, Binance API

Tags: c++, rest, winsock2

I'm trying first to connect with Binance api endpoint which is /api/v3/ping.
However I'm getting "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" response, what should be updated in this code?

```
    int main()
    {
        WSADATA wsa;
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        std::string request;
    
        std::cout<<("Initialising Winsock...\n");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        {
            std::cout<<("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    
        std::cout<<("Initialised.\n");
    
    
        if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << ("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    
        std::cout << ("Socket created.\n");
    
        const wchar_t* IP = _T("52.84.198.235");
        InetPton(AF_INET, IP, &server.sin_addr.s_addr);
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(443);

        if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<("connect error\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        std::cout<<("Connected\n");
    
        request += "GET /api/v3/ping HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.binance.com\r\n\r\n";
    
        if (send(s, request.c_str(), strlen(request.c_str()), 0) < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<("Send failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << ("Data Send\n");
    
        std::string response;
        int resp_leng;

        response = "";
        resp_leng = BUFFERSIZE;
        while (resp_leng)
        {
            resp_leng = recv(s, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
            if (resp_leng > 0)
                response += std::string(buffer).substr(0, resp_leng);
        }
   
        std::cout << response << "\n";
    
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I was using info from a few sites and stackoverflow questions, I'm wondering if it can be about SSL?

Comment: `cout << (1, 2);` will just output "2", also see the "comma operator" from your C++ docs, that part is already severely broken in your code. In any case, yes, the server will probably expect HTTPS as protocol, which you don't provide. Since this is non-trivial, consider using a dedicated HTTP client library for that instead. Since you're on MS Windows, there is even something built into the OS, I believe. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, your code should be a [mcve]. It's close, but only that.

Comment: `response += std::string(buffer).substr(0, resp_leng);` -- If `buffer` contains embedded nulls, you are truncating the output when you construct a `std::string` like this: `std::string(buffer);`.  Never use functions that stop on the first null byte, such as this version of the `std::string` constructor.  Instead, construct the initial `std::string` using `resp_length`, i.e. `std::string(buffer, resp_length);` and drop the unnecessary `substr` call.

Comment: Then this: `std::cout << response << "\n";` should be `std::cout.write(response.c_str(), response.size()); std::cout << "\n";` -- The reason is that again, plain `std::cout << response` stops at the first null byte.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I've checked SSL doc [RFC6101](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6101) and indeed there is lot of work and as I have already written own HMAC and SHA256 libraries to my project- it's enough. I've used WinHttp lib and it solves the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie BTW, when you look at the code [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview) and in the place where we have `printf( "%s", pszOutBuffer );` I've put string variable that takes the value like `s=pszOutBuffer;`. Why s is empty when using it after if instruction? I think declared string s has it's own memory address so it should 'copy' value of the pszOutBuffer. Because when doing cout<< still inside the if, it will write it properly in the console.

Comment: @Jacob Again, do *not* use functions that stop on the first null byte.  Always use the return value of `recv`, which gives you the length of the returned data.  When you use `%s` as the format specifier, this will stop at first null byte in the string.  If the string has embedded nulls, you will not see all of the output.  Also, it does not matter if you see the output when you use `cout <<` -- my point is that it is not the correct way to display response data.  For verification, print out the return value of `recv()` and see what the actual value is.

Comment: `strlen`, `strcpy`, `'%s'` format specifier, `std::string x = y;` `cout << string` -- None of those (and probably more I can think of) are not the way to store or display data coming over a socket.  If you are not using the return value of `recv()` in some way to generate the string or to print out the string, you are doing things wrong.  All of those things mentioned are built-in to stop processing at the first null byte.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand you very well, but like I wrote earlier I'm using now WinHttp, not WinSock2 to use `recv()`. Actually I've copied the code from the [MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview) and it works, but I don't understand why I'm losing value of the global string where I'm trying assign`LPSTR pszOutBuffer;` to. It works inside `if` but not after this, how it's possible?

Comment: //Update: putting every char from `pszOutBuffer` to char vector using for loop works, I can use it after `if` statement. Again, assigning `pszOutBuffer` to string or char* works only inside `if`, after the closing bracket, if the var was string the it shows nothing, and if it's char* then I get error like "use of a potentially uninitialized local pointer variable "

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just solved the issue, I had to use `s+=pszOutBuffer ;` instead of `s=pszOutBuffer ;` (where s is string) as it looks operation in this request runs twice and string was empty because it was null byte probably assigned to s? That's why using `vector <char>` worked. Need to check further. Thanks!